# Ember.js update models from application controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I need to update data every minute and on some specific events.

My idea is to create an action in `ApplicationRoute`, that would find the current router and evoke the `model()` method again.

But how can I access other routes from `ApplicationRoute`?
Maybe there are any other ideas to make it?

Comment: Using model.reload() would perhaps be better than invoking the model hook again http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reenvoke the `model` hook.

The matter is that most store data retrieval methods, for example, `store.findAll()` (ex `store.find()`) return live arrays. A live array will automatically update its content whenever new records appear in the store or existing records are removed.

So all you need is to repopulate the store.

A good place to periodically fetch the data is a service.

Also, you can enable/disable periodic data retrieval from within routes. Simply create a mixin that would enable data retrieval in the service when the route is visited and disable when the route is left.